# Can't connect to MySQL server on ********* '1040, u'Too many connections' only from certain directory

Tags: python, mysql, pytest, pymysql

When I run my projects regression I get multiple tests failing with a 
`1040, u'Too many connections error` 
from MYSQL. What is odd about this is that no settings have changed all of sudden this error is appearing. Even stranger when I went to debug the problem I discovered that I get the same error if I run certain tests from the main test directory with `py.test -ktest_this_data_stuff -n10` get the same errors. If I go into the suite directory and run the same `py.test -ktest_this_data_stuff -n10` the tests do not error out with a MYSQL error.  Perplexed to say the least.

Comment: You have a `-n10` in the first version, and not in the second. I don't know `py.test` very well, but if that means something like "test 10 times in parallel" it could easily explain the difference. Even "test 10 times serially" could explain the difference if your code doesn't properly clean up the connection and `py.test` runs the tests all in the same interpreter instance.

Comment: Sorry that is a typo both are running tests in paralell

Comment: OK, then you should [edit] your question to fix that typo.

Comment: @abarnert roger that.